# Как реализовать onepage-scroll если высота секций разная?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, прокрутка

Все отлично работает, когда все секции одинакового размера (стандартная ситуация).
Но вот нужно сделать перелистывание, когда одна секция не такая как все))

Comment: Не стесняемся прикладывать свой код к вопросу. Какой код, когда все секции одинаковые, как выглядит типовая секция, пример-другой нестандартной секции.

Answer (score 0):

Оно того не стоит)

Есть вариант(это еще light version) задавать каждой секции data атрибут, в нем прописывать нужные цифры. Потом считывать его и прокручивать на это значение. На мой взгляд оно того не стоит.